# Organize firebase functions in multiple files | Deploy error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So based on [this Medium post](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da) I tried to split my firebase functions into different files.
My index.js looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const glob = require("glob");
const camelCase = require("camelcase");
const files = glob.sync('./**/*.f.js', { cwd: __dirname, ignore: './node_modules/**'});

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

for(let f=0,fl=files.length; f<fl; f++){
  const file = files[f];
  const functionName = camelCase(file.slice(0, -5).split('/').join('_')); // Strip off '.f.js'
  if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
exports[functionName] = require(file);
  }
}
```

My file test.f.js, where my function is located, is in some subfolders and looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.addNew = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
...
})
```

My subfolders are called "dev" and "User", the file is called "Test" and my function "addNew"

When I try to deploy I get the following error:

`⚠  functions[devUserTest-addNew(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named devUserTest.addNew`

I hope someone can provide a solution to this problem.

Tanks!